# Callback for Multiple AWS Lambda execution completion

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Here is my problem:

> I have to compare a candidate object with some criteria with millions of other candidates in db. Since lambda allows only 5 minutes of execution so it causes timeout.

My Solution:

> I planned to do this comparison with 10,000 chunks of candidates so I have to call 10 lambda functions (through SNS) to process 100,000 candidates and then save results of each lambda in some DynamoDB table. But how to get a callback when all lambda functions are done processing so that I can collect those results for individual lambdas and then calculate final results. How to achieve this or is there any better way to acheive my goal. Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Rather than struggling with 10 lambda functions that do the same thing, why not create an EC2 / Elastic Beanstalk instance and run your application in there?

Comment: It is customer's requirement @GerritvanHuyssteen.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? Are you trying to find one best candidate of the many being compared? Or, do you need to rank the top X based upon some criteria?

Comment: @JohnH I am doing De-Duping. Removing duplicate candidates and retrieving more accurate and complete data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if AWS Lambda is truly a good fit for your use case. However just focusing on the main part of your question, you could use [DynamoDB Atomic Counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) to determine when all processing is complete. You would do the following:

- Initially insert a record in DynamodB with a field like `numberOfLambdaCalls` attribute set to the number of concurrent executions you are kicking off, and a `completedLambdaCalls` attribute set to `0`.
- As each function completes, as part of updating the DynamoDB record they would increment the `completedLambdaCalls` attribute atomically.
- Each function could check the returned result of the update to see if they were the one to complete the processing like `if numberOfLambdaCalls == completedLambdaCalls` and if they are, perform whatever action is necessary to trigger your response.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Your answer is almost correct. it actually led me to a more accurate solution which is `Condiditional Update` http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate

Comment: I'd like to know what is specifically incorrect about my answer. And how does Conditional Update solve your problem exactly?

Comment: From AWS docs `However, in a banking application, it would be safer to use a conditional update rather than an atomic counter`. Atomic counter can cuase wrong counter in cases of concurrent updates while conditional update allows you to add a conditional expression. e.g. two concrrent requests get same value of counter, lets say 10. We then can add a condition on update that existing value should be 10. So 1st one will update it 11 and second one will fails and on retry it will update the counter to 12.

Comment: That was specifically talking about incrementing an account balance in a banking application. If you are just incrementing a count, then atomic counters is exactly what you want. If you use conditional updates then you will have a race condition where some of your concurrent updates will never happen.